# Does using Mind Control require two attack rolls?

Tags: attack, numenera, cypher-system

Using Mind Control requires that the user touches the target and that the target be of a certain level or lower. An unwilling target can, in general, try to resist an unwanted effect.

Against an unwilling target of a valid level, does using Mind Control require a Speed attack roll to touch them, then an Intellect attack roll to establish control? If not, then what does it take?

Comment: Do you have the game manuals available to offer up where the confusion comes from? (I have not played this game, but sometimes it helps to present which parts of a game's rules create the lack of clarity).

Answer (score 1):

Using a touch based special ability on an unwilling target is resolved as an attack, as described on page 208 of the Cypher System rulebook. The example speaks about Healing Touch, that is an Intellect based task as Mind Control, but does not state that a different Might or Speed attacks are involved.

So, unless the action you are storytelling does not require it, for the sake of simplicity you can adjudicate that a single Intellect task is enough to activate Mind Control (see Adjudicating, page 378 of the Cypher System rulebook).

An attempt to chase and touch an NPC on a crowd market in order to use Mind Control is different in this, because the character must reach his victim in a typical Speed based situation prior to activate his special ability.